# Python & C: Trying to create a dict of all declared variables and functions and their types of a .c source file

Tags: python, c

Basically trying to create a dict of all declared variables and functions along with their types of a .c source file. Does anyone think I missed anything?

```
#!usr/python
import string
import re
from types import *
from pprint import pprint

varDict = {}

def find_substring(needle, haystack):
    index = haystack.find(needle)
    if index == -1:
        return False
    if index != 0 and haystack[index-1] not in string.whitespace:
        return False
    L = index + len(needle)
    if L < len(haystack) and haystack[L] not in string.whitespace:
        return False
    return True

f = open('example.c')
varTypeList = []

for varType in open('typesfile.txt'):
        varTypeList.append(varType[:-1])

for line in f:
        for varType in varTypeList:
                if find_substring(varType,line):
                        var = re.search('\s*[\*_a-zA-Z]+[\*_a-zA-Z0-9]?', line.split(varType)[1])
                        if type(var) is not NoneType:
                                varDict[var.group(0)] = varType
pprint(varDict)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code is fundamentally broken. What about comments and the preprocessor? And just by eyeballing the code I doubt very much that it parses declarations remotely correctly.

This is the wrong approach. `string.find` will only take you so far. You need to *parse* the code to get reliable information. The easiest way to do this is to use a library, such as [libclang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/).

Answer (score 1):

This library looks like a great option for solving your problem in Python: http://code.google.com/p/python-ctags/

Answer (score 1):

The code in `find_substring()` can be accomplished in one line in regular expressions.